# React Router how to change class name of an element in a component when route changes?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have routes in the following way:

```
<Route path="" component={Sidebar}>
    <Route path="pages/about" component={PageFactory}" />
    <Route path="news" component={NewsFactory}" />
</Route>
```

Now I want to add a class to sidebar component when route changes. So, if route becomes "/pages/about", I want to add "is-open" className to an element in Sidebar component. If route becomes "/", I want to remote the className from the element in Sidebar component.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each component gets some useful properties.

In the sidebar component you can do this:

```
const Sidebar = React.createClass({
   render() {
     let { location:{pathname, params, query} } = this.props; // router props
   }
});
```

Then you can detect if `pathname` is `about` then do your `is-open`